# Cropping Image view

Tags: android, image, view

i M passing a bitmap from one activity to other, after taking the screen shot

```
                Bitmap bitmap;
                bitmap = takeScreenshot();
            try {
                //Write file
                String filename = "bitmap.png";
                FileOutputStream stream = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                //Cleanup
                stream.close();
                bitmap.recycle();

                //Pop intent
                Intent in1 = new Intent(this, FinalImageShare.class);
                in1.putExtra("image", filename);
                startActivity(in1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

here i am getting the image in other activity , the problem is that the tool bar height is also coming (i m hiding the toool bar by setVisibility, )i want to crop the image so that toolbar height wont come.TIA

```
     imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
    try {
        FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you hide the toolbar before taking screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use `createBitmap` method, like so:**

```
resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, yourwidth, yourheight);
```

Where `bitmap` is the bitmap you create, and `resizedbitmap` is the cropped one.

createBitmap() method takes as parameter in this case: bitmap, start X, start Y, width and height.

You can use those two methods to get your width and height:

```
bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()
```

Check also this link to learn about the `createBitmap` method:

[Developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

**Or you can use the drawing cache property for this, like this :**

```
View main = findViewById(R.id.view);
Bitmap screenshot;
main.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(main.getDrawingCache());
main.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

**Or similar to the last one, `ctx.getWindow().getDecorView()` View to get full screen bitmap cache:**

```
View view = ctx.getWindow().getDecorView();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Bitmap bmap = view.getDrawingCache();    

int contentViewTop = ctx.getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop(); /* skip status bar in screenshot */
Storage.shareBitmapInfo = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmap, 0, contentViewTop, bmap.getWidth(), bmap.getHeight() - contentViewTop, null, true);

view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Hope this helps!